# Serializers: Customising nested relationships

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following data structure which is similar to what is shown in the [serializer nested relationships example](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).

Models:

```py
class Entities(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="name of the object")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, help_text="description of the object")

class EntitiesAVP(models.Model):
    entity = models.ForeignKey(Entities, related_name='attributes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attribute = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False, null=True,
                                 help_text="name of the attribute")
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, null=True,
                             help_text="value of the attribute")
```

As per the example, I am exposing this data in my API using the following serializers:

```py
class EntitiesAVPSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EntitiesAVP
        fields = ('attribute', 'value')


class EntitiesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    attributes = EntitiesAVPSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Entities
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'attributes')
```

This exposes my example data in the following JSON structure:

```py
[
    {
        "name": "Test Entity",
        "description": "Description of test entity",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "attribute": "attribute 1",
                "value": "value 1"
            },
            {
                "attribute": "attribute 2",
                "value": "value 2"
            },
            {
                "attribute": "attribute 3",
                "value": "value 3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What I would like, is to present my attributes in the following format:

```py
[
    {
        "name": "Test Entity",
        "description": "Description of test entity",
        "attributes": {
                "attribute 1": "value 1"
                "attribute 2": "value 2"
                "attribute 3": "value 3"
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

To try and achieve this, I have played with various types of related field. The closest I can get is the [CustomRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#example_1), which produces a string instead of some JSON.

```py
class EntitiesAVPSerializer(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return "{}: {}".format(value.attribute, value.value)

[
    {
        "name": "Test Entity",
        "description": "Description of test entity",
        "attributes": [
            "attribute 1: value 1",
            "attribute 2: value 2",
            "attribute 3: value 3"
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm pretty new to this and feel like I'm not too far away from what I am trying to achieve. Can someone please give me a little push in the right direction?

**Edit:**

The solution from [Hugo Luis Villalobos Canto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55446549/11287068) returns a dictionary, which is an awesome start, but that gives me a list of dictionaries instead of a single dictionary:

```
class EntitiesAVPSerializer(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return {value.attribute: value.value}

[
    {
        "name": "Test Entity",
        "description": "Description of test entity",
        "attributes": [
            {
                "attribute 1": "value 1"
            },
            {
                "attribute 2": "value 2"
            },
            {
                "attribute 3": "value 3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Desired output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Test Entity",
        "description": "Description of test entity",
        "attributes": {
                "attribute 1": "value 1"
                "attribute 2": "value 2"
                "attribute 3": "value 3"
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you are getting a string, thats what you are returning from serializer's `to_representation()`.

What you have to do is to return a dictionary, that is what you expect:

```
class EntitiesAVPSerializer(serializers.RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return {value.attribute: value.value}
```

**EDIT**

If what you want is a dictionary, I'll advice you to use a **SerializerMethodField**, that allows you full control:

```
class EntitiesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    attributes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Entities
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'attributes')

    def get_attributes(self, instance):
        attributes_dict = {}

        attributes = EntitiesAVP.objects.filter(entity=instance.entity)
        for attribute in attributes:
            attributes_dict[attribute.attribute] = attribute.value

        return attributes_dict
```

Comment: Thanks Hugo, This returns a list of dictionaries (one dict for each row), which is close. What I'm looking for is a single dictionary which includes all rows.

Comment: You Sir, are a star!

Comment: I'm glad you found the answer. Happy coding!